# Как определить некоторую область, куда был наведен курсор и нажата левая кнопка мыши?

Tags: xna, c#, спрайт

есть список из спрайтов spriteList
параметры спрайта (textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame,sheetSize, speed)
всего в списке около 145 элементов, мне нужно перемещать их каждый по-отдельности, при нажатии на них левой кнопкой мыши. Как это можно сделать?
если в метод Update запихнуть сей код, то по нажатию в любую область первый спрайт из списка туда и переноситься.
как модифицировать под мои запросы?

if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButtоn == ButtonState.Pressed)

{

foreach (Sprite element in spriteList)

{

element.Update(gameTime, Game.Window.ClientBounds);

}

}

Comment: Я не знаком с XNA, но неужели нельзя подписать каждый из спрайтов на Click?

Comment: то есть ??

Comment: ну, я предполагаю, что спрайты являются визуальными элементами, и содержать event Click. если это не так, надо действовать по-другому.

Comment: Тут все таки по-моему нужно другое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Увы, до XNA пока не добрался, но некоторые поиски в интернете дают свои плоды.

В общем-то алгоритм прост. В Ваш foreach по спрайтам надо добавить проверку, находится ли текущее положение мышки в области спрайта (Intersect).

Далее запоминаем этот спрайт (тут явно придётся некие ID им присваивать, пожалуй), ну и на следующем обновлении двигаем (с движением, как я понимаю, Вы разобрались)

Если с английским проблем особых нет, то вот аналогичный [вопрос](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/53705.aspx).

Comment: возможно, если пользоваться массивом, не будет возни с айдишниками -_-

Comment: а зачем id? запоминайте просто сам спрайт

Comment: создать новый список?